# Can i add an attribute to an @XmlCDATA generated tag?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata, moxy

My current XML-File used some CDATA values.
I try to read it in with JAXB but i don't get access to the attribute type

```
<root>
    <name type="myType" ><![CDATA[<h1>myName</h1>]]></name>
</root>
```

I have an class like this

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlCDATA;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlCDATA
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

How can i get access to the **type** attribute?

Comment: What happened to `@XmlAttribute(name="type")`?

Comment: What i would normally do is, i would create a class name annotated with @XmlRootElement(name = "name")  and within this class i can create a variable with @XmlAttribute(name="type"). This works fine.  But i don't have any clue how to handle the CDATA-Reference in this way.

Comment: Why do you insist ont he CDATA tag? JAXB will escape all content anyway. It will give you the same result.

Comment: You are right. If i use this modal in all of my project, than i can use @XmlValue for read and write. But we have multiple project and in some of them we cannot use the modal for now. This indicates that we don't want to change the xml at all. Especial for an escaped value like CDATA.

Comment: If you have a model you cannot really change but need to change serialization, you should switch to EclipseLink MOXy, where you can fully customize marshalling without touching code.